# Mailing program for some reason is not working when i type in 100+ as mass

Tags: java, if-statement

In the country of Rahmania, the cost of mailing a letter is 40 sinas for letters up to 30 g, 55 sinas for letters over 30 g and up to 50 g, 70 sinas for letters over 50 g and up to 100 g, and then an additional 25 sinas for each additional 50 g or part thereof. Write a program that prompts the user for a mass and then gives the cost of mailing a letter having that mass.

```
class Mail
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("What is the mass of you letter?");
    int mass=In.getInt();

    if(mass<30)
    {
      System.out.println("The cost for mailing your "+mass+"g would be 40 sinas.");
    }
    else if(mass>30&&mass<50)
    {
      System.out.println("The cost for mailing your "+mass+"g would be 55 sinas.");
    }
    else if(mass>50&&mass<100)
    {
      System.out.println("The cost for mailing your "+mass+"g would be 70 sinas.");
    }
    else
    {
      int changingMass=0;
      mass=changingMass;
      changingMass=changingMass-100;
      changingMass=changingMass/50;
      int totalSinas=changingMass*25+(70);

      System.out.println("The cost for mailing your "+mass+"g would be "+totalSinas+" sinas.");
    }
  }
}
```

If i type in like 200 for the mass i get 0g and 20 sinas. Why i even try to read the code and to me it is good.
What i think is the problem-changingMass=changingMass/50;

Comment: Use floating point for your calculations.  Integer division truncates.

Comment: decimals? double??

Answer (score 1):

You have initalized the following variable.

```
int changingMass=0;
```

Then you assign it to your reqired variable **mass**(which is a user input). That makes `mass=0` below.

```
mass=changingMass;
```

Then you have used that `0` for all your calculations, which is a terrible mistake. That is why you always get 20 sinas in the else clause.

```
changingMass=changingMass-100;
changingMass=changingMass/50;
int totalSinas=changingMass*25+(70);
```

Don't modify the user input `mass`.

```
int changingMass=0;
//use the user input 'mass' for the first calculation of changingMass
changingMass=mass-100;
changingMass=changingMass/50;
int totalSinas=changingMass*25+(70);
```

Hope you got it.

Comment: Wow one line of mistake changed this program.Thanks for the help it works now!!